# How can I get all email list from Active Directory using C#?

Tags: c#, email, active-directory

I want to get all email addresses from Active Directory. Below, I tried this case but it didn't get all emails. I need all emails such as `ObjectClass=group`, `ObjectClass=user` etc...

I tried these,

```
deSearch.Filter = "(|(ObjectClass=user)(ObjectClass=group))";

deSearch.Filter = "(mail=*@abc.com)";
```

Full code:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
deSearch.Filter = "(mail=*)";

SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in results)
{
    if (sResultSet.Properties["Mail"].Count > 0) 
    {
        if (sResultSet.Properties.Contains("Mail")
        {
            mailPackage.Mail = sResultSet.Properties["Mail"][0].ToString();
        }
        mailList.Add(mailPackage);
    }
}
return mailList;
```